# How to find xpath to the image element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a below HTML Code which points to a SVG (image) Element on the screen

```html
<div _ngcontent-c25="" class="chart-div ng-star-inserted">
      <!---->
      <!----><div _ngcontent-c25="" class="pie-div ng-star-inserted" d3-pie="">
    <svg width="80" height="80">
     <g transform="translate(40,40)" width="80" height="80"><g transform="translate(40,40)"></g>
      <path d="M2.4492935982947065e-15,-40A40,40 0 0,1 30.83714902626715,-25.476856947665098L13.876717061820216,-11.464585626449294A18,18 0 0,0 1.102182119232618e-15,-18Z" fill="#3182bd"></path>
      <path d="M30.83714902626715,-25.476856947665098A40,40 0 0,1 36.923912424205994,15.382610028521366L16.615760590892698,6.922174512834615A18,18 0 0,0 13.876717061820216,-11.464585626449294Z" fill="#6baed6"></path>
      <path d="M36.923912424205994,15.382610028521366A40,40 0 0,1 3.4424059772594435,39.851597723149425L1.5490826897667496,17.93321897541724A18,18 0 0,0 16.615760590892698,6.922174512834615Z" fill="#9ecae1"></path>
      <path d="M3.4424059772594435,39.851597723149425A40,40 0 1,1 -7.347880794884118e-15,-40L-3.3065463576978533e-15,-18A18,18 0 1,0 1.5490826897667496,17.93321897541724Z" fill="#c6dbef"></path>
     </g>
    </svg>
   <div class="attrFilter-tooltip" id="attributeFilterTooltipCountry" style="display: none; position: fixed; left: 1567px; top: 325px; z-index: 1000; background: rgb(238, 238, 238); box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 0px 0px 5px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); width: 100px; text-align: center;"><div class="attrLabel" style="font-weight: bold;">Germany</div><div class="attrCount">693</div><div class="attrPercent">51.4%</div></div></div>
      <!----><p _ngcontent-c25="" class="filtered-text ng-star-inserted">
        no value filtered
      </p>
      <!---->
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </div>
```

I am able to find the element till the div tag but if I try to access the element in SVG and its child chrome is unable to find the element

XPath : //div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted'] - this works perfectly until div 
but if I try to access its child element SVG and path it's not locating it at all (though code is visible on screen)

Xpath I've tried : //div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/svg/g/path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ3eH.png)

on-screen the element would look like as in the below screenshot. 
[image]

The element is actually a svg image on screen (Pie Chart) once we hover on that it displays a popup of the corresponding location data

Comment: can you use `querySelectorAll` instead?

Comment: or you can use `//div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path']`

Comment: Perfect Bravo //div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path'] your xpath works fine ... Thanks

Comment: There is another syntax which I think is cleaner, but you need a `namespaceResolver` in your `document.evaluate`

Comment: could you please share that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xpath needs to be `//div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path']` - found by searching for xpath + svg

There is another syntax `//div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/svg:svg/svg:g/svg:path` - and using the NSresolver argument, you can make it work as follows

```js
const xpath = "//div[@class='pie-div ng-star-inserted']/svg:svg/svg:g/svg:path";
let result = document.evaluate(
  xpath, 
  document, 
  prefix => prefix === 'svg' ? 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' : null,
  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
  null
);

for (var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
  console.log(result.snapshotItem(i).getAttribute('fill'));
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c25="" class="chart-div ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-c25="" class="pie-div ng-star-inserted" d3-pie="">
    <svg width="80" height="80">
      <g transform="translate(40,40)" width="80" height="80"><g transform="translate(40,40)"></g>
        <path d="M2.4492935982947065e-15,-40A40,40 0 0,1 30.83714902626715,-25.476856947665098L13.876717061820216,-11.464585626449294A18,18 0 0,0 1.102182119232618e-15,-18Z" fill="#3182bd"></path>
        <path d="M30.83714902626715,-25.476856947665098A40,40 0 0,1 36.923912424205994,15.382610028521366L16.615760590892698,6.922174512834615A18,18 0 0,0 13.876717061820216,-11.464585626449294Z" fill="#6baed6"></path>
        <path d="M36.923912424205994,15.382610028521366A40,40 0 0,1 3.4424059772594435,39.851597723149425L1.5490826897667496,17.93321897541724A18,18 0 0,0 16.615760590892698,6.922174512834615Z" fill="#9ecae1"></path>
        <path d="M3.4424059772594435,39.851597723149425A40,40 0 1,1 -7.347880794884118e-15,-40L-3.3065463576978533e-15,-18A18,18 0 1,0 1.5490826897667496,17.93321897541724Z" fill="#c6dbef"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="attrFilter-tooltip" id="attributeFilterTooltipCountry" style="display: none; position: fixed; left: 1567px; top: 325px; z-index: 1000; background: rgb(238, 238, 238); box-shadow: rgb(153, 153, 153) 0px 0px 5px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); width: 100px; text-align: center;">
      <div class="attrLabel" style="font-weight: bold;">Germany</div>
      <div class="attrCount">693</div>
      <div class="attrPercent">51.4%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p _ngcontent-c25="" class="filtered-text ng-star-inserted">
    no value filtered
  </p>
</div>
```